# Meteor: Reactive joins exposes intermediate data

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using [publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) to perform a reactive join (I'm sure the specific package does not matter). And I am seeing that the intermediate data gets pushed to the client.

In the following example:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('messages', function(userId) {  
  return {
    find: function() {
      return Meteor.users.find(
        { 'profile.connections.$': userId }
      );
    },
    children: [{
      find: function(user) {
        return Messages.find({author: user._id});
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

All the users that has userId in `profile.connections` get exposed to the client. I know that can create a mongodb projection so the sensitive stuff is not exposed. But I was wondering if I can just prevent the first find() query cursor from getting to the client at all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to only publish messages for a particular user if that user is a connection with the logged on user?  If so, maybe something like this would work:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('messages', function(userId) {
  return {
    find: function() {
      return Meteor.users.find(this.userId);
    },
    children: [{
      find: function(user) {
        return Meteor.users.find(
          { 'profile.connections.$': userid }
        );
      },
      children: [{
        find: function(connection, user) {
          return Messages.find({author: connection._id});
        }
      }]
    }]
  };
});
```

That would be equivalent to something like :

```
Meteor.publish('message',function(userId) {
  var user = Meteor.users.find({_id : this.userId, 'profile.connections.$' : userId});

  if (!!user) {
    return Messages.find({author: userId});
  }

  this.ready();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is quite close, I was doing that same thing you suggested. But the problem is that if you make new connection, the messages from that new connection would not show up unless you refresh.

Comment: I was thinking you only wanted messages from one connection displayed.  So you are looking to show messages from all the user's connections?